# Using a Mux to switch between reading and driving a wire

Tags: fpga, verilog, system

I have been doing some googling and cannot seem to come up with an answer for this. The way I understand a mux is that it is basically a 2 way switch. I understand it is mostly used to select inputs for a single output.

I am trying to implement a Verilog system in an FPGA that is able to drive a signal to a pin and also read the voltage level from that pin. Can I use a mux to switch between driving the signal and also reading from that same pin?

I will not be trying to read and drive the signal at the same time. The voltage level of that signal will basically determine if I intend to drive that pin.

Comment: Depends on the part. But this is direction control, not a mux.

Comment: The mux is not bi-directional

Comment: Which FPGA are you using? If you mean the actual pin of the chip, it may have an output-enable line.

Comment: It is a Xilinx Spartan 3 and yes this would be direction control.

Comment: How are you going to read the voltage level of the signal in an FPGA? Do you have an internal ADC? Of you have an external one? This is kind of confusing!

Answer (score 2):

You want a tristate IO buffer, not a mux.  This sort of thing is done in Verilog all the time:

```
module tristate(pin, in, out, oe);
    inout wire pin;
    output wire in;
    input wire out;
    input wire oe;

    assign in = pin;
    assign pin = oe ? out : 1'bz;
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

The one you are talking about is a bidirectional IO. You have to declare the intended signal as inout and use a tristate buffer. You can read the inout port at all times and do the processing regardless whether you are using it as a input or output.

Tristate buffer is used to avoid the data collision between your output data and the external input data. When you are expecting external input data you must disable the tristate buffer to avoid the data collision.

Answer (score 0):

Generally within an FPGA, for every node in the circuit there will be a single gate that is always responsible for driving it; everything else connected to that node will regard it as an "input".  Although it is common for inter-chip connections to use a single pin for input and output, that is not done within an FPGA.  Instead, at the boundary of the chip there will be circuitry which takes two or more input signals from the guts of the FPGA that say whether it should output anything and if so, what (and possibly how strong), and will output a signal to the guts of the FPGA saying whether a high or low signal is present on the pin.  The pin that connects to the outside world will be bidirectional, but everything on the FPGA side of the interface will be unidirectional.

There are some sorts of logic where this kind of design can be a bit restrictive.  For example, if one wanted to read 8 bits of data from one of 64 devices, having an 8-wire bus which is connected to all of the devices, and having one of the devices output data on that bus (using a total of 512 pass-gates and 128 6-input NOR gates, along with and 20 wires interconnecting the devices [send addresses in true- and complement forms]), might be more efficient than having to route 8 groups of four signals to each of 128 4-input muxes, and then run the outputs of those to 32 more 4-input muxes, whose outputs would then feed eight more 4-input muxes (a total of 164 4-input muxes, plus a lot of interconnect wiring).  Still, having every input always be connected to exactly one output avoids issues of data contention, and generally works pretty well.